# Unsafe Code requires `unsafe` command line option to be specified Monodevelop 4.0.12

Tags: build, monodevelop

I'm try to build the project [SDRShare](http://rtlsdr.org/softwarelinux) but When I come to the step *buiild-all* I get the following mistake

[image]

I try to do this:

- [Opción 1:](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Unsafe-code-on-MonoDevelop-2-4-2-OS-X-td3640685.html) Right click your project > Options > Compilation
  (General) > Allow unsafe code
- click Project - 'SolutionName' Options - General - Allow 'unsafe'
  code

  And then [How to compile unsafe code in MonoDevelop 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958273/how-to-compile-unsafe-code-in-monodevelop-2-4)

My Monodevelop GUI don't has this options
[image]

where is this option on Monodevelop 4.0.12?

**SOLUTION**

Well [this is the solution that I fund](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/AllowUnsafeBlocks-not-parsed-correctly-td1511000.html), there aren't parameters to build unsafe code, I found  some files that has this configuration, the files has extension `.csproj` when you need to say that allow unsafe code
that has the following tags: `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` , if you put false inside this tags don't allow unsafe code . This part of code shoul be inside of block `<PropertyGroup>`

This is a part of code:

```xhtml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>..\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>

    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>false</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules>true</CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
                 <!-- This is the solution -->
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>

  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Did you try the steps outlined in that link you provided for monodevelop?

Comment: off course, was the first that I did

Comment: So that means you don't have those options either, for specifying additional compiler options?

Comment: Yes sr, the only thing that I get is the image that  I posted, Is the first time that I use Monodevelop, so I don't know where is this options, less in this version 4.0.12

Comment: And have you looked through the option pages you do have, for something similar to "Additional compiler options"?

Answer (score 3):

I found this to work on Mono Develop version 5.9.6.

See screenshot.

[image]